# How Implement reverse proxy on nginx to add authentication on flink job manager

Tags: nginx, apache-flink

I want to add authentication on flink job manager, my friend recomend me to using nginx as reverse proxy and put auth process on there using htpasswd.
i tried to create password using htpasswd and it succed.
But the problem is when i add pass_proxy on nginx/sites-available/default
it succes to redirect to the web, it looks like wont load the CSS file.
 [nginx wont load css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvJIo.png)

this is some configuration i tried :

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        server_name localhost;

        location /flink_sit {
                proxy_pass http://wrkdlkdev01:45404/#/overview;
        }
        location /flink_uat {
                proxy_pass http://wrkdlkdev01:41097/#/overview;
        }
```

Comment: Where is the jobmanager page trying to load the CSS from?